# Summing up the first n elements of each row in a 2D array in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have the following array in Scheme:

```
((64 28 52 24) (68 29 62 29) (20 72 48 60) (45 102 75 51) (36 84 72 64) (80 9 63 60) (20 56 72 24) (57 53 88 63))
```

I want to form a 2d array by summing up 'combining' **n** rows in a single row. For example, let's say that **n= 2** for the first two rows we will be combined into one row `((132 57 114 53) ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so you have a list of things (rows) in this case, and you want to apply an operation `f` (adding rows) on them `n` at a time. So I'd make a general function for that `(on-chunks n f lst)`.

Then your operation can be defined as `(on-chunks 2 row-sum matrix)`. It's easy to define row-sum: `(define (row-sum row1 row2) (map + row1 row2))`.

For the chunking part, I would recommend defining a helper function for it that takes one chunk off the front of the list and returns two values: that chunk, the rest of the list. Then `on-chunks` can be implemented with recursion by calling that function. e.g. `(chunk-aux 2 '(a b c d e f)) ;=> (a b) (c d e f)`.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon the answer above, a fold would be a very easy way to recursively sum up n rows, while srfi-1's `(take)` and `(drop)` procedures will split the two-dimensional list as needed:

```
(use srfi-1)    

(define (sum-rows xs)
  (foldl (lambda (x acc)
           (map + x acc))
         (car xs)
         (cdr xs)))

(define (merge-rows xs n)
  (cons (sum-rows (take xs n))
        (drop xs n)))
```

Though performance wouldn't be ideal for absurdly long lists, as `(take)` and `(drop)` would be redundant computations.